# How to test done part of ajax in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jasmine

I really like [this resource](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/testing-ajax-event-handlers-using-jasmine-spies.html) for AJAX in general and it works in terms of testing a `success` or `error` function that's within the AJAX parameters.

However, when I instead choose to not have a `$.ajax({ ... success: ... })` and choose to have a `.done()` outside, I'm not sure how to test. Please help amend my simple spec, thanks!

**Code**

```
function itWorked() {}

function sendRequest(callbacks, configuration) {
  $.ajax({}).done(function(response) {
    itWorked()
  });
}
```

**Spec**

```
fdescribe("Ajax Tests", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(window, "itWorked")
    deferred = $.Deferred().done(function() { })
    spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake(deferred)
    sendRequest()
  })
  it("should work", function() {
    expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled() // pass
    expect(window.itWorked).toHaveBeenCalled(); // fail
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, probably the example in the question is not the same you are running local, but it should fail in the line `spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake(deferred)` because `callFake` expect a function and `deferred` is not. Instead, `deferred` should be a *resolved Promise* and use `.and.returnValue` instead of `.and.callFake`.

Here is a working example:

```
  function itWorked() {
    console.log("It worked!!");
  }

  function sendRequest(callbacks, configuration) {
    $.ajax({}).done(function(response) {
      itWorked();
    });
  }

  describe("Ajax Tests", () => {

    beforeEach(function() {
      spyOn(window, "itWorked").and.callThrough();
      deferred = $.Deferred().resolve(); // Call resolve
      spyOn($, "ajax").and.returnValue(deferred); // Use return value
      sendRequest();
    });

    it("should work", function() {
      expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled(); // pass
      expect(window.itWorked).toHaveBeenCalled(); // pass
    });
  });
```

Note that I've added `console.log("It worked!!");` and use `.and.callThrough();` just to double check in the console that *"It worked!!"* was logged.

When calling [$.Deferred().resolve()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) you can pass a *mocked* response to deal with in your `.done` or `.then` callback. Something like `.resolve({ success: true })`. [Check an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392072/unit-testing-jquery-getjson-function-errors-with-the-fail-method-using-jasmine/53405718#53405718)

Hope it helps